# Application of Cantor-Schroder-Berstein Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am doing a proof to show that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ (set of real numbers) is equal to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

I have an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, defined and proven.

As well as proved the existence of an injection from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, by proving an injection exists from $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ defined by $f(x,y)=0.x_1y_1x_2\dots$ using infinite decimal expansions.

I know that since $(0,1)$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{R}$, there exists an injection. however the question requires defining an injection $g\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. How do I define said injection.

The solution of the problem is simple using CSB, however im having trouble defining the second injection after proving its existence.

Comment: The relation (relational) equipotency is of equivalence. You need to notice that the equipotency of $(0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$ implies the equipotency of $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

Comment: ok given that(0,1)×(0,1) is equivalent  with R×R, do i still need to define the injection, or is existence sufficient to apply CSB

Comment: By CSB there is bijection, if you composite it with the injection, it will give you the desired injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the isomorphism of sets,then
 the function $g(r,s)=(f^{-1}(r),f^{-1}(s)) $ from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to 
$(0,1)\times(0,1)$ is a bijection, so
the function
$$h=f\circ j\circ g,$$ where $j$ is the injection that you find, is an injection.

Comment: Ok great, now that I see it I understand the solution

Answer (score 1):

Find an injection $f':[0,1)\times [0,1)\to [0,1).$ Find an injection $h:\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z.$

For $r\in \Bbb R$ let $r=[r]+${$r$} where $[r]\in \Bbb Z$ and {$r$}$\in [0,1).$

For real $r_1,r_2$ let $g(r_1,r_2)= h([r_1],[r_2]) +f'(${$r_1$},{$r_2$}).